# Decidability Problem

Tags: turing-machines, automata

given a turing machine M over the input alphabet $\Sigma $ , any state q of M and a word w $\epsilon\Sigma $* , does the computation of M on w visit the state q ?

Is this problem decidable ?

Comment: What do you have so far

Comment: Short version: if you could do this, you could solve the halting problem by running the algorithm for the halting state(s).

Answer (score 3):

Let P(M,q,w) = "the computation of M on w visit q"

If we suppose P décidable, then the problem P' defined as :

P'(M,w) = w \in L(M)

is decidable.

Proof : 
This a decision procedure for P'. Let M be a machine and w a word. 
For each accepting state q of M, we run P(M,q,w).  If the answer 
 is "yes" for some q, we return "yes". Otherwise, we return "no".

Since it is well known that P' isn't decidable (Rice theorem), we conclude P isn't decidable.

Comment: Someone told me that it is semi decidable !

Comment: Yes, it is semi-decidable. You just need to run M on w with a universal turing machine and return "yes" if you reach state q.